# When calling a c function using ctypes.CDLL in Python, the function always gets 0 passed along as argument

Tags: python, c++, c, ctypes, neovim

The c function I am trying to call:

```c
#include <stdio.h>    
#include <stdlib.h>    
  
int main(int argc, char *argv[]){       
    long long int n = atoll(argv[1]);    
    printf("main(%lld)\n", n);    
    int m = 0;         
    while (n > 1) {           
        m++;                  
        if (n % 2 == 0) {   // even    
            printf("%lld = %lld/2 \n", n/2, n);    
            n = n/2;    
        }    
        else {    
            printf("%lld = 3*%lld+1 \n", 3*n+1, n);    
            n = 3*n + 1;    
        }    
    }        
    printf("Collatz(%lld) is '%d'\n", n,m);    
    return m;    
}
```

My python code that attempts to call it with parameter 4

```py
from ctypes import *    
import os, sys                                                                    
                                                                                    
print("you typed:", sys.argv[1])                                                  
                                                                                    
filename = sys.argv[1].split(".")[0]                                              
                                                                                    
os.system(f"gcc -c -fPIC {filename}.c -o {filename}.o && gcc {filename}.o " \     
           f"-shared -o {filename}.so")                                           
       
soFile = CDLL(os.getcwd() + "/" + filename + ".so")    
       

soFile.main(4)       # <----------
```

In vim I run the following:

```
:!python test.py "collatz-loop"                                                
you typed: collatz-loop
main(0)
Collatz(0) is '0'
```

Notice how the output is 0. Even if I change the parameter to something other than 4, the output is always 0.

If I try to change `soFile.main(4)` to something with, say, two parameters, like `soFile.main(2, 4)`, I get

```
:!python test.py "collatz-loop"

shell returned 139
```

**Why is this happening, and how do I fix it?**

- I am new to c by the way, though very familiar with Java. They seem very alike syntactically.
- Yes, I did remember to save/write the python and c file before running the .py file.

Comment: Unless I'm misremembering something, shouldn't argv[0] be the first argument put in, not argv[1]?

Comment: argv isn't passed to `main` so `atoll(argv[1])` doesn't work.

Comment: Why is this in `main` in the first place? You're loading it as a shared lib, you dont need main. Just change it to `int collatz(long long n)` or something similar as the sig and it should be fixed.

Comment: @SuperStormer The reason why it's a main function is so that I also have the option to compile the c function to an executable and do e.g. `./collatz-loop 4` (which by the way works perfectly fine!). Do you think I can fix it without changing the signature of the c-main-function?

Comment: Ok, then split it into 2 funcs, `main` and `collatz` and make `main` just pass `atoll(argv[1])` to `collatz`.

Comment: @SuperStormer Alright, I guess that's the way it's done in c ... just seems kind of strange. Thanks by the way.

Comment: Its not really c-specific - If this was java, you wouldn't import `Collatz` and then call `Collatz.main("123")`, you would just do `Collatz.collatz(123)`

Comment: @SuperStormer Oh, I see, that actually makes a lot of sense then!

Comment: How did you compile the code? You can't just call into `main` in an executable, because you're bypassing the C-runtime initialization code. But if you compiled it as a DLL or .lib, then it should work.

Comment: Also, `main` requires two arguments, `argc` and `argv`. You seem to be calling it with just one argument.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

TLDR for comment thread:
You should split it into 2 funcs, `main` and `collatz` (`int collatz(long long n)`) and make main just pass `atoll(argv[1])` to collatz, so you can run it normally as an executable and also from your python script file as a shared library. You also need to set the argtype in ctypes to long long(I think it defaults to int).

C:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int collatz(long long n){
    int m = 0;
    while (n > 1) {
        m++;
        if (n % 2 == 0) {   // even
            printf("%lld = %lld/2 \n", n/2, n);
            n = n/2;
        }
        else {
            printf("%lld = 3*%lld+1 \n", 3*n+1, n);
            n = 3*n + 1;
        }
    }
    printf("Collatz(%lld) is '%d'\n", n,m);
    return m;
}

int main(int argc, char *argv[]){
    long long int n = atoll(argv[1]);
    printf("main(%lld)\n", n);
    collatz(n);
}
```

Python:

```
from ctypes import *
import os, sys

print("you typed:", sys.argv[1])

filename = sys.argv[1].split(".")[0]

os.system(f"gcc -c -fPIC {filename}.c -o {filename}.o && gcc {filename}.o " \
           f"-shared -o {filename}.so")

soFile = CDLL(os.getcwd() + "/" + filename + ".so")


soFile.collatz.argtypes = [c_longlong]
soFile.collatz(4)
```

Note: Not directly related to this issue, but you should check to make sure `argc > 2` in your C code to avoid an out of bounds read if no args are passed.